# How to change default email reset link for the WordPress reset a password

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to change the default WordPress e-mail URL so that it is not directed to the `wp-login.php` page after the user registers but another page.

Below is a screenshot showing the section of a WordPress email containing the URL I want to alter;

[image: WordPress email screenshot containing the default login page URL]

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress User Registrations, Password Reset emails are using the pluggable.php file. (/wp-includes/pluggable.php) . There are two ways to achieve your request.

1. Modify the /wp-includes/pluggable.php file. : Not preferred/advised but an easy way. For the example above modify the line number 1903 (Referring to branch 5.0.2 https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.0.1/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L0)
2. Extend the functionality with functions.php 
   In the following example, the user notification will redirect the user to different URL.

   ```
   add_filter( 'wp_new_user_notification_email', 'custom_wp_new_user_notification_email', 10, 3 );
   function custom_wp_new_user_notification_email( $wp_new_user_notification_email, $user, $blogname ) {
       $wp_new_user_notification_email['subject'] = sprintf( '[%s] New user %s registered.', $blogname, $user->user_login );
       $wp_new_user_notification_email['message'] = sprintf( "%s ( %s ) has registerd to your blog %s.", $user->user_login, $user->user_email, "To Change your password visit: https://google.com" );
   return $wp_new_user_notification_email;
   }
   ```